# How to assign objects to specific user?

Tags: python, django, object, project, assign

I am working on a tasks app using Django, I want to assign a task to the user who created it.

**the app model:**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    due_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-pub_date"] # Ordering by the pub date field
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**the app views:**

```
class TaskListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'task_list.html'
    login_url = 'login'


class TaskCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'task_create.html'
    fields = ('title', 'content')
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('task_list')

class TaskUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'task_update.html'
    fields = ('title','content',)
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('task_list')

class TaskDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'task_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('task_list')
```

**any help would be helpful to me since I am just a beginner :D**

Answer (score 0):

In the create view, define an new function:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.create_by = self.request.user
    form.instance.update_by = self.request.user  # this is for the update view.
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Another small hint:

`def get_success_url(self)` could just be `success_url = reverse('task_list')` (as a class variable) in your case as you don't use `self` in you function anyway.

Another small hint:

No need to put `login_url = 'login'` in each view if you define `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'`, `LOGIN_URL = '/login/'` and `LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'` in the settings.py